# Stored Procedure Insert multiple rows

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a table,

```
FruitCrateID
FruitID
```

Now `FruitID` and `FruitCrateID` have a many-to-many relationship. I have a strongly typed dataset I need to create add and update stored procedure.

Now I can use `foreach` to add `FruitID` and `FruitCrateID` to database but there will be several calls for example,

```
FruitCrateID - 124
FruitID - 23
FruitID - 245
FruitID - 242
and so on ....
```

What I created so far.. I want to add them all in a single query..

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * FROM FruitShoppingList WHERE FruitCrateID = @FruitCrateID))
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM FruitShoppingList WHERE FruitCrateID = @FruitCrateID
    END

INSERT INTO dbo.FruitShoppingList (FruitID, FruitCrateID)
    VALUES  ( @FruitID, @FruitCrateID)
```

Comment: Try to do this at front end rather.

Comment: I mean to say do this data manipulations at front end rather than the back end.

Comment: The query you posted doesn't make any sense. Why bother deleting a row and then immediately reinserting it? To answer your question you should look into table valued parameters. Then you can pass in the entire dataset. Then inside your procedure you just need to insert the rows that don't already exist.

Comment: @SeanLange You are right, sorry it was a typing mistake, I fixed it now

Comment: I would take off the EXISTS check. Why hit the table twice? Just do the delete. Of course that will still not work for your entire dataset because you are using scalar values.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for a [table valued parameter](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2010/06/t-sql-tuesday-007-summertime-in-sql.html) You can populate it from a dataset and, assuming you don't do something silly when you pass it to SQL Server, will be treated as an atomic operation - all of it's going in or none of it.

```
IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        sys.types T
    WHERE
        T.name = 'CONTRIVED_EXAMPLE'
)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Dropping type dbo.CONTRIVED_EXAMPLE'
    DROP TYPE dbo.CONTRIVED_EXAMPLE
END
PRINT 'Creating type dbo.CONTRIVED_EXAMPLE'
GO
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Type: dbo.CONTRIVED_EXAMPLE
-- Author: Bill Fellows
-- Date: 2010-06-07
--
-- This is a user-defined table type demonstrating the syntax
-- for a table valued parameter
--
-- See also:
--
-- Modified:
--
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TYPE
    dbo.CONTRIVED_EXAMPLE AS TABLE
(
     twitter_handle varchar(15) NOT NULL
,    have_met bit NOT NULL
)
GO

IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        sys.tables T
    WHERE
        T.name = 'CONTRIVED_EXAMPLE_TABLE'
)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Dropping type dbo.CONTRIVED_EXAMPLE_TABLE'
    DROP TABLE dbo.CONTRIVED_EXAMPLE_TABLE
END
PRINT 'Creating table dbo.CONTRIVED_EXAMPLE_TABLE'
GO
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Type: dbo.CONTRIVED_EXAMPLE_TABLE
-- Author: Bill Fellows
-- Date: 2010-06-07
--
-- This is a boring table demonstrating the syntax
-- for a table valued parameter
--
-- See also:
--
-- Modified:
--
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE
    dbo.CONTRIVED_EXAMPLE_TABLE 
(
    row_id int identity(1,10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,    twitter_handle varchar(15) NOT NULL
,    have_met bit NOT NULL
)
GO

IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT
        SO.*
    FROM
        dbo.sysobjects SO
    WHERE
        SO.id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.EchoBack')
        AND OBJECTPROPERTY(SO.id, 'IsProcedure') = 1
)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Dropping stored procedure dbo.EchoBack'
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.EchoBack
END
GO
PRINT 'Creating stored procedure dbo.EchoBack'
GO
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Function: dbo.EchoBack
-- Author: Bill Fellows
-- Date: 2010-06-07
--
-- This procedure handles merging
--
-- Recordsets:
-- The contents of our table valued parameter will be echoed back to the 
-- caller.
--
-- Side-effects:
-- None
--
-- See also:
-- your mom
--
-- Modified:
--
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.EchoBack
(
    @tvp dbo.CONTRIVED_EXAMPLE READONLY
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT
        T.*
    FROM
        @tvp T

END
GO
PRINT 'Granting rights for dbo.EchoBack'
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.EchoBack TO public
GO
DECLARE @p1 dbo.CONTRIVED_EXAMPLE 
INSERT INTO @p1 values('billinkc', 1)
INSERT INTO @p1 values('peschkaj', 1)
INSERT INTO @p1 values('mikeSQL', 1)
INSERT INTO @p1 values('SQLChicken', 0)

SELECT * FROM @p1

EXECUTE dbo.EchoBack @p1
GO
IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT
        SO.*
    FROM
        dbo.sysobjects SO
    WHERE
        SO.id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.TwitterAdd')
        AND OBJECTPROPERTY(SO.id, 'IsProcedure') = 1
)
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Dropping stored procedure dbo.TwitterAdd'
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.TwitterAdd
END
GO
PRINT 'Creating stored procedure dbo.TwitterAdd'
GO
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Function: dbo.TwitterAdd
-- Author: Bill Fellows
-- Date: 2010-06-07
--
-- This procedure handles merging
--
-- Recordsets:
-- Business rule violations (optional)
--
-- Side-effects:
-- 0-N rows written to twitter table
--
-- See also:
-- CONTRIVED_EXAMPLE (your mom)
--
-- Modified:
--
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.TwitterAdd
(
    @tvp dbo.CONTRIVED_EXAMPLE READONLY
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    MERGE
        dbo.CONTRIVED_EXAMPLE_TABLE DESTINATION
    USING
        (SELECT twitter_handle, have_met FROM @tvp T) AS SOURCE (twitter_handle, have_met)
        ON (SOURCE.twitter_handle = DESTINATION.twitter_handle)
        -- Never forget I met someone
    WHEN MATCHED AND DESTINATION.have_met = 0
        THEN UPDATE SET DESTINATION.have_met = SOURCE.have_met
    WHEN NOT MATCHED
        THEN INSERT(twitter_handle, have_met) VALUES (SOURCE.twitter_handle, SOURCE.have_met)
        -- merge statements must be terminated by a semi-colon
        -- and don't you forget it!
        ;

END
GO
PRINT 'Granting rights for dbo.TwitterAdd'
GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.TwitterAdd TO public
GO
```

At this point, you can see how the TVP works. The only remaining step is to tie it in to your .NET code. Something like

```
/// <summary>
/// This method demonstrates the ease of passing a dataset in
/// as a TVP
/// </summary>
public static void TSQLTuesday007()
{
    string connectionString = @"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True";
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString);
    System.Data.DataTable dataTable = null;

    // note that my data table does not have to be the same
    // as my UDTT, nor do my columns have to have the same name
    // Types-yes. Ordinal, probably so
    dataTable = new System.Data.DataTable("Sample");
    dataTable.Columns.Add("tweep", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
    dataTable.Columns.Add("have_met", System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean"));

    // add rows to my data table but really, this could be any source
    dataTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { "billinkc", true });
    dataTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { "BrentO", true });
    dataTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { "buckwoody", false });

    // Hooray for #sqlsat35 and meeting Jen & Sean
    dataTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { "MidnightDBA", true });

    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection connection = null;
    System.Data.DataSet results = null;
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand command = null;
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader dataReader = null;
    connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionString);
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        command = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("TwitterAdd");
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Connection = connection;

        // Assigning a table valued parameter looks much like any other parameter
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter tvp = command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tvp", dataTable);

        // this is the only special sauce (not required but helpful)
        tvp.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured;
        tvp.TypeName = "dbo.CONTRIVED_EXAMPLE";

        dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (dataReader.HasRows)
        {
            results = new System.Data.DataSet();
            results.Tables.Add();
            results.Tables[0].Load(dataReader);
            // PPrint(results);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```